# Does quarkus-maven-plugin support multi-module projects?

Tags: quarkus

I'm trying to convert a multi-module Maven project from vanilla Java EE 8 to Quarkus, and it seems that `ArcAnnotationProcessor` throws exceptions about unsatisfied dependencies for all injection points referencing dependencies located in a different module.

Is there any workaround, short of merging the modules?

Answer (score 4):

Answering my own question:

According to the [Quarkus CDI guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference),

> The bean archive is synthesized from:
>
> - the application,
> - application dependencies that contain a beans.xml descriptor or a generated Jandex index (META-INF/jandex.idx),
> - and Quarkus integration code.

After adding a `beans.xml` to each of my reactor modules, ArC no longer complains about missing dependencies.

Comment: Hi, I'm also working on a multi-module maven project. It seems that hot deployment is not active on multi-module projects. I mean, if you make a change in one module, are you able to see automatically your changes?

Comment: Answering my own question: it seems that multi-module for Quarkus will be supported on next release 0.14.0, for more info see https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/1484. I've got the answer from the comments of this blog https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/04/12/migrating-java-applications-to-quarkus-lessons-learned/

Comment: would be nice to have some official link to multi-module-sample